# Error processing validation. ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Tags: javascript, oracle, jquery, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have period=3day/week/month , start_date and end_date. When I select start_date for eg. 12-DEC-2013.. then i want to validate an end_date is around start_date + period(3day) + 2day(default).. so end_date will be 16-DEC-2013.. I wrote the code here..

```
declare

v_period date;

begin

if :P104_TYPE_PERIOD = 'DAY' then
v_period  := ((TO_DATE(:P104_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')+(nvl(to_number(replace(:P104_COURSE_PERIOD,',', '0'))),0)))+2);
end if;

if :P104_TYPE_PERIOD = 'WEEK' then
v_period  := ((TO_DATE(:P104_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')+(nvl(to_char(to_number(replace(:P104_COURSE_PERIOD,',', '0'))),0)*7))+2);
end if;

if :P104_TYPE_PERIOD = 'MONTH' then
v_period  := ((TO_DATE(:P104_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')+(nvl(to_char(to_number(replace(:P104_COURSE_PERIOD,',', '0'))),0)*30))+2);
end if;

if v_period  < :P104_END_DATE then
return false;
end if; 
end;
```

After I run the page, this message appear:

```
Error processing validation.
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: `period=3day` ? You cannot convert `3day` into a number, this gives a conversion error.

Comment: actually that 3day i used different item.. 
P104_COURSE_PERIOD=3  P104_TYPE_PERIOD=DAY..
thats why i put there,

Comment: if :P104_TYPE_PERIOD = 'MONTH' then
v_period  := ((TO_DATE(:P104_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')+(nvl(to_char(to_number(replace(:P104_COURSE_PERIOD,',', '0'))),0)*30))+2);
end if;

Comment: could you please print all the host variables starting with ':' in the BEGIN block first and show us the output.?

Comment: :P104_COURSE_PERIOD = 3

Comment: :P104_TYPE_PERIOD = DAY / MONTH / WEEK

Comment: :P104_START_DATE = 22-DEC-2013

Comment: :P104_END_DATE = 22-DEC-2013 + 3 + 2 = 26-DEC-2013

Comment: First of all this code cannot compile, this expression is wrong: `+(nvl(to_number(replace(:P104_COURSE_PERIOD,',', '0'))),0)`

Comment: even if the error you face now is resolved, you may have to rethink, ur methodology

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `:P104_COURSE_PERIOD` is a `NUMBER`;

Your block was replacing commas with zero, can you provide the possible values if it is **NOT** a `NUMBER`.

```
   declare
        v_period date;
        v_date_offset_factor NUMBER;
    begin
        if :P104_TYPE_PERIOD = 'DAY' then
            v_date_offset_factor := 1;
        ELSIF :P104_TYPE_PERIOD = 'WEEK' then
            v_date_offset_factor := 7;
        ELSIF :P104_TYPE_PERIOD = 'MONTH' then
            v_date_offset_factor := 30;
        END IF;
        v_period  := TO_DATE(:P104_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + (:P104_COURSE_PERIOD * v_date_offset_factor ) + 2;
        if v_period  < TO_DATE(:P104_END_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') then
            return false; -- Do you return something?
        end if; 
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line( SQLERRM||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace );
    end;
```

Please try the above PL/SQL

**To be noted:** 
*You multiply the date with 30, I guess you do some month calculations, but there's month with 28 and 31 days too. Did you consider them ?*